# Multilingual string to Number

Tags: c++, c, macos, unicode

I have following code:

```
    const wchar_t *  hstr    = L"\x0967\x0968\x0969\x096a"; //1234 in Devnagari script.
    unsigned long long   u1;
    long long    n1;


n1  = wcstoll   (hstr, NULL, 10); // _wcstoi64 on Windows
u1  = wcstoull  (hstr, NULL, 10); // _wcstoui64 on Windows
LOG(L"String: \"%ls\" is %lld as long 64"),   hstr, n1);
LOG(L"String: \"%ls\" is %llu as long 64"), hstr, u1);
```

On the log on Windows, it is working fine and number gets converted.

On Mac OS X, n1 and u1 are 0 not 1234. What is the problem here?
Are multilingual numbers are not supported to wcstoll on Mac OS X?

Comment: "In other than the "C" locale, additional locale-specific subject sequence forms **may** be accepted." It's not required to accept Devanagari digits, if the C library on your Mac does at all, you'd need to set the proper locale.

Answer (score 0):

`wchar_t` is not neccessarily unicode numbers. It is locale dependant, so maybe look at setting your locale first. Just a guess

Comment: In initialization on Mac OS X, I am calling setlocale(LC_TYPE, ""). What else I need to do?

Comment: You could try a unicode encoding for devangari. Maybe `hi_IN.UTF-8`. Just a guess. I think `locale -a` lists all available locales on your system